# Spring Boot - search for word in ArrayList and return it in GET

Tags: java, arrays, list, spring-boot

I have an array list in my **Service** class:

```
@Service
public class PeopleService {

    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(  

        new Person("1", "John", "Smith"),
        new Person("2", "Peter", "andna"),
        new Person("3", "Fred", "Rieger")
                    ));
```

And what i want to do is that i want to create a method which would search for a palindrome word in this List and ten return it via GET request.
My **Controller** will hopefully be this one:

```
//GET palindrome
@RequestMapping("/people")
public List <Person> getPalindromePeople() 
{
    return peopleService.getPalindromePeople(); 
}
```

I know that for a palindrome search i should adapt this code (code is not mine, i need to modify it):

```
int i1 = 0;
int i2 = word.length - 1;
while (i2 > i1) {
    if (word[i1] != word[i2]) {
        return false;
    }
    ++i1;
    --i2;
}
return true;
```

The problem is that i can't figure out how to adapt that code to search for palindrome words in my Array List, because it consists of 3 objects, and each of them has 3 parameters (id, name, surname). 
Could anyone give me a little hint with this one? I appreciate.

Comment: Are you checking palindrome for all 3 fields i.e id, firstName, lastName or just one of them. You can create a method for palindrome checking and loop through your objects passing each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the list and call call for palindrome check.
Here is a piece which checks for palindrome based on firstName

```
List<Person> persons;
List<Person> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Person person: persons){
    if(istPalindrom((person.getFirstName().toCharArray())))
        resultList.add(person)
}
return resultList
```

Based on your logic you can add check on fistName and lastName or firstName or lastName by changing the `if` condition